Sharepoint On-premises Alert Notification is not working after changing somethings
I created a SharePoint survey like this
enter image description here
And then I create an alert with the settings like this:
enter image description here
I tried to make any things change like editing the responses from other users
enter image description here
but when I checked mail, it only show the mail about creating alert and didn't have the editing
enter image description here
I tried to setting the alert with different options but it still not get email about the other actions like editing, deleting
How can I get the other actions notification?
Thank you
problem solves quickly

You can try Sharepoint Designer to create workflow to send email notifications.
